# How to use R basic function in Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector markovchainSequencecpp() {
  CharacterVector data = CharacterVector::create("a","b","c","d");
  // randomly select 3 observation using sample
  // return result;
}
```

I want to use sample function of R for random selections. What are the different ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

See [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) as well as the [R header files](https://github.com/wch/r-source/tree/trunk/src/include).

In short, there is a well defined API but it is *in no way a match* to the R functionality.  Many things are not exported -- `sample` would be one such thing:

```
edd@max:~$ grep sample /usr/share/R/include/*
grep: /usr/share/R/include/R_ext: Is a directory
edd@max:~$
```

In some cases we built packages just to get particular functionality, [RApiSerialize](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/RApiSerialize/index.html) is one example.

Comment: can we pass R sample function as an argument to markovchainSequencecpp